# How to Skip null and execute query in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

I want if user have subscribed plan with id 8 he should receive error he can not subscribe. if not he should able to subscribe. I tried below code. but it can not work when users has no record in table. it gives error "`$sit=>null"` I want it should skip checking null or not null .and focus only on plan id 8.

```
public function newbonus()
{
    $sit = Deposit::where('user_id', Auth::user()->id)->first();

    if($sit->plan_id == 8){
      {
         session()->flash('message', 'You have Claimed Free Bonus Already.');
            Session::flash('type', 'warning');
            Session::flash('title', 'warning');
            return redirect()->back();

    }else{

        $data['general'] = GeneralSetting::first();
        $data['site_title'] = $data['general']->title;
        $data['basic'] = BasicSetting::first();
        $data['page_title'] = "Free Bonus";
        $data['payment'] = Payment::first();
        $data['plan'] = Plan::whereStatus(1)->get();
        return view('user.bonus-new',$data);
       }
}
```

Comment: change `if($sit->plan_id == 8)` to `if(!is_null($sit) && $sit->plan_id == 8)`

Comment: and when it will be null then?

Comment: mean when user has no record in that table

Comment: Exactly, if it is null, means that the user didnt have any `Deposit` Record, so he didnt have any `plan_id` 8

Comment: i need it should work both if it is null and when it is not null. with is code user which have record is able to subscribe again

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
if(optional($sit)->plan_id == 8)
```

With this, you have an empty Deposit Model, so the null exception dosnt appear.

Regards.

Comment: Call to undefined function App\Http\Controllers\optional()

Answer (score 0):

So you want to be able to enter the control structure if the Id is 8, or if it's null?  What's happening there is if there are no results, the entire variable is `null`, and you find yourself looking for the property on something that's not actually an object.

There's a few ways to handle this, take your pick.  First, fun-fact, Eloquent Collection results are just children of regular Collections.  `$model->first()` tells Eloquent\Builder to hit up MySql for just one result.  `$model->get()` tells is to get *all* results and return a Collection.  That means `$model->first()` and `$model->get()->first()` are logically identical, with the second line there potentially being a DB performance hit.  *Potentially* a performant hit.  In your case though you're querying on an Id field that's likely only capable of returning one result.  So by tapping into the Collection `first()` instead of the Eloquent\Builder `first()`, you get access to it's support for a default value:

```
$sit = Deposit::where('user_id', Auth::user()->id)->get()->first(null, app(Deposit::class));
```

Alternatively, same concept, different execution:

```
$sit = Deposit::where('user_id', Auth::user()->id)->first() ?: app(Deposit::class);
```

In both cases, you're dummying-in an empty Model in place of the absent result, so that `$sit->plan_id` will return `null` instead of throwing an error that `$sit` is itself null.

Lastly, you could just add a new `if` condition:

```
if(is_null($sit) || $sit->plan_id == 8){
```

Only drawback here is if the content of your control structure is also expecting `$sit` to be an object.

My personal preference would be Option #2.